# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=["lb"])
async def leaderboardie(ctx, x=1):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People",
                       description="This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet", color=discord.Color(0xfa43ee))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}",  inline=False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Error i keep getting:
`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

It's basically about a leaderboard based on users wallets, but every time i get this error for some reason, if you know the solution tell me.

Comment: `client.get_user(id_)` is returning `None`.

Comment: how to fix it tho

Comment: Either skip that member, or put in a replacement value, or get the name some other way.  Think of the thing you want your program to do in that situation, and then write the code that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing `client.get_user(_id)`, you need to turn on the server members gateway intent in the developer portal. If you do not want to turn on this intent, you can use:

`await client.fetch_user(id)`